# How to add a new column of values to an imported (from parquet) Dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask

I have a big dataset saved in `parquet` format with 40 files in total. The index is a `datetime` index.

In my script, I read in the dataframe, and want to add a new column to this dataset. I don't have a dataset available for you for testing, but the (pseudo, untested) code looks something like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.delayed
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet
import random
from numpy import array

CUSTOM_DATE_PARSER = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
IMPORTED_DF = read_parquet("./data/regression_df.parquet", parse_dates=['time'], date_parser=CUSTOM_DATE_PARSER, index_col='time')

new_column = array([random.randint(1,30) for _ in range(len(IMPORTED_DF))])
```

Now, I want to add that column to the dataset. I try using `assign` but am running into this error:

```
IMPORTED_DF.assign(new_col=dd.from_array(new_column))

ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

I saw in a GitHub post, a hacky workaround is to just reset/set the index column, so new code and error looks like:

```
    df = df.reset_index().set_index('time') # 'time' is the name of my index column
    df.assign(label=dd.from_array(new_column))

  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 4935, in assign
    data = elemwise(methods.assign, data, *pairs, meta=df2)
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 6020, in elemwise
    args = _maybe_align_partitions(args)
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\multi.py", line 173, in _maybe_align_partitions
    dfs2 = iter(align_partitions(*dfs)[0])
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\multi.py", line 133, in align_partitions
    divisions = list(unique(merge_sorted(*[df.divisions for df in dfs1])))
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\toolz\itertoolz.py", line 264, in unique
    for item in seq:
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\toolz\itertoolz.py", line 156, in _merge_sorted_binary
    if val2 < val1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'
```

Another option I thought of was to assign the `array` to a `Series` instead, and use `dd.from_pandas()` in the `assign`, however it then asks for a chunksize or npartitions to be assigned, which I don't know either of them. When I saved the dataset initially, I used a `row_chunk_size` of `10000`, however I perform some `nan` dropping before exporting, so that's not a true `chunksize` I don't think, which leaves `npartitions`. How could I find that number out?

Or better still, how can I just add this darn column to the dataset?

Comment: `df['new_column'] = new_column ` doesn't work?

Comment: Negative, same error as `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'`